# Messaging system query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an internal messaging system where user can send/reply message to one or multiple users. I want the show inbox like gmail system. The original message will be listed in the table. If there is reply corresponding to that message, the replies count is shown at the side. If either of message or reply is unread, I want row to show in bold. I have following table structure.

**msg_inbox table**

```
message_id
message_subject
message_body
sender_id
recipient_id
read_status
message_date
marked_important
```

**msg_reply table**

```
reply_id
message_id
reply_subject
reply_body
reply_sender_id
reply_recipient_id
reply_read_status
reply_date
```

I have following query so far but does not seem to work

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  COUNT(r.reply_id) replycount,
  (SELECT 
    reply_read_status 
  FROM
    sc_messages_reply 
  WHERE message_id = r.message_id 
    AND reply_recipient_id = r.reply_recipient_id 
    AND reply_read_status='0'
  ) AS reply_read_status,
  r.reply_sender_id,
  r.reply_date 
FROM
  sc_messages m 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_messages_reply r 
    ON m.message_id = r.message_id 
WHERE m.sender_id = '34' 
  OR m.recipient_id = '34' 
  OR r.reply_sender_id = '34' 
  OR r.reply_recipient_id = '34' 
GROUP BY m.message_id 
ORDER BY m.marked_important DESC,
  m.message_date DESC,
  r.reply_date DESC
```

I must have gone somewhere wrong in above query, It will be great if someone point it out.

HERE IS THE SAMPLE DATA

**msg_inbox**

```
insert into `msg_inbox`
(`message_id`, `message_subject`, `message_body`, `sender_id`,
 `recipient_id`, `read_status`, `message_date`, `marked_important`) 
 values (1, 'This is test message',
         'This is test message body apart from subject', 
         12, 34, 1, '2012-09-29 07:49:37', 1), 
        (2, 'This is yet another message',
         'This is yet another subject', 13, 34, 1, '2012-09-29 07:51:00', 0);
```

**msg_reply**

```
insert into `msg_reply`
(`reply_id`, `message_id`, `reply_subject`, `reply_body`, `reply_sender_id`,
 `reply_recipient_id`, `reply_read_status`, `reply_date`)
 values (1, 2, 'Test reply', 'test body\r\n', 
         34, 13, 1, '2012-09-29 07:51:46'),          
        (2, 2, 'Reply of the reply\r\n', 'Message reply of the reply',
         13, 34, 1, '2012-09-29 07:52:32'),
        (4, 1, 'Re.This is test message', 
         'Naturally I took it upon myself to solve this problem for all of you :) I created this plugin to be as general purpose as possible. As a result it ended up being vastly more customizable than any other jQuery auto-complete plugin. Not only that, I am using actual jQuery. For some reason all the other &amp;#34;jQuery&amp;#34; plugins don&amp;#39;t really take advantage of the radness that is jQuery. Consequently, my plugin ended up being',34,12,1,'2012-09-30 14:37:40'),(5,1,'Re.This is test message','Well its all good sir',12,34,0,'2012-09-30 15:07:38');
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, query is not displaying results as expected

Comment: Ok then, Can you please add some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, The only part not working seems to be subquery,  Lets say for `message_id=1`, the original message is read so `read_status=1` this is ok, but one of the reply to this message id i unread, the subquery is what i used for that, and that is returning null value instead of 0 even though there is unread message reply for `message_id=1`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, I have added insert query for sample data and also i have updated the query please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to `JOIN` the table

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  COUNT(r.reply_id) replycount, unreaded.reply_read_status,
  r.reply_sender_id,
  r.reply_date 
FROM sc_messages m 
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT *
     FROM sc_messages_reply  
     WHERE reply_read_status = '0'
) unreaded ON m.message_id = unreaded.message_id
INNER JOIN  -- You can also join the readed messages like this:
(
     SELECT *
     FROM sc_messages_reply  
     WHERE reply_read_status = '1'
) readed ----
LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_messages_reply r ON m.message_id = r.message_id 
  AND unreaded.reply_recipient_id = r.reply_recipient_id
WHERE m.sender_id = '34' 
  OR m.recipient_id = '34' 
  OR r.reply_sender_id = '34' 
  OR r.reply_recipient_id = '34' 
GROUP BY m.message_id 
ORDER BY m.marked_important DESC,
  m.message_date DESC,
  r.reply_date DESC
```

Comment: @LoVeSmItH What error? Post it please. Can you also setup a demo in [Sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/). Thanks

Comment: The error is `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm.message_id = unreaded.message_id
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT *
     FROM sc_' at line 12`

Comment: @LoVeSmItH  Sorry, I forgot the keyword `ON` after `unreaded` see my edit.

Comment: Still showing same error at `line 12`. i think you need `ON` in inner join as well

Comment: Also second INNER JOIN doesnot have condition after `ON`

Comment: @LoVeSmItH Yes I leave it for you to complete it any way give me some time to setup a demo for you to make it easy to try that query.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH I made a [demo query in sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a339e/6) please see it and edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think i have solved the problem i have changed the subquery to

```
SELECT 
    reply_read_status 
  FROM
    sc_messages_reply 
  WHERE message_id = r.message_id 
    AND  reply_read_status='0' AND reply_recipient_id='34'
```